# Is there any way to get a "char" from the user in java?

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

I have researched and there does not seem to be a way to get a char from the user. If there is any way to do this I would be greatly appreciated if someone could show me.

Comment: Read in a String and get the first letter from it.

Comment: why not just use java.system.in.read()? Reads exactly one byte

Answer (score 0):

[`String.charAt(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

Example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char ch = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```